# Recommendations for .NET components that handle and improve TIFF files

Tags: .net

I am currently looking for a .NET component that fulfills the following requirements.

- TIFF files

  - Extracting single pages as images
  - Writing the images to new TIFFs
- Support for colored TIFFs/Images
- Improving the TIFF files (deskew is a must, despeckle etc optional)
- Royalty-free deployment on servers
- Fully architecture independent (only one assembly for x64/x86)

I have found that [Libtiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) is capable of handling the tiff files, but the API is still very complex and it cannot improve the files.

For improvements, I am trying out AForge.NET(http://www.aforgenet.com/), but its filters require converting the images to specific pixel formats depending on the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are now probably going with [GdPicture.NET](http://www.gdpicture.com/)<strike>, which has the drawback of not fulfilling the platform requirement (--> seperate assemblies for x64 & x86).</strike>

However, it was the only affordable component for some of the weird formats we are using around here (OJPEG as input, files that Windows(GDI+) can't open...).

Edit: The component now provides a fully managed core assembly, thereby eliminating the need on our side to build multiple versions of our software.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the freeimage library? http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/ I can't quickly tell whether it can edit/improve the TIFF, but it looks to be able to do the rest.

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot do the improvements, but the API seems to be a bit easier to use than LibTiff.NET(for what I need).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for [ImageKit](http://www.imagekit.com/imagekitnet.html) component.

> a 100% managed .NET imaging component... With the ImageKit.NET, application programmers can quickly and easily add powerful imaging capabilities to their .NET applications.
>
> The ImageKit.NET contains not only Windows Form controls but also Web Form controls and supports VS2008, VS2005, and VS2003.
>
> There are numerous sample programs included illustrating common imaging tasks. Each sample shows one or two tasks, keeping the sample programs easy to understand and allowing you to use the samples to aid in building your imaging applications.
>
> The ImageKit.NET can retrieve digital images from TWAIN scan devices and digital cameras. It can load and save image data in a variety of formats. It contains numerous effect filters and image transformation methods allowing you to resize, rotate, compose images, and do much, much more.

Comment: Why?  What makes it good?  What's not so good about it?  Please expand your answer.

Comment: Some files were wrongfully deteced as single-page, whereas some could not be opened at all. I will contact support, If they can fix it, it may be a possibe solution.

Comment: After some contact with the support: ImageKit can not open files that Windows itself is unable to open(GDI+), which ruled it out for our project.